# Getting a "UserID not exists" error when using jtf_rs_resource_pub.create_resource API to import an employee as a salesperson in Oracle EBS

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-ebs, oracle-apps

jtf_rs_resource_pub.create_resource(p_api_version => 1.0, p_category => 'EMPLOYEE', p_start_date_active => sysdate, p_source_id => ln_person_id (per_all_people_f.person_id)
, p_user_id => ln_user_id,
p_user_name => lc_user_name, p_resource_name => 'XXX', p_source_number => lc_user_name, p_source_name => 'XXXX'
, p_source_first_name => 'XXXXX',
p_source_last_name => 'XXXXXXX', p_source_business_grp_id => fnd_profile.value_specific('XXXX'), x_return_status => lc_return_status
, x_msg_count => ln_msg_count, x_msg_data => lc_msg_data,
x_resource_id => ln_resource_id, x_resource_number => lc_resource_number);

COMMIT;
getting invalid userID error

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this assumes you've already created an associated FND User, which can be done with the fnd_user_pkg.createuser - here's an [example](http://www.shareoracleapps.com/2016/04/api-to-create-application-user-in-oracle-apps-r12-fnduser-createuser.html).